# A linear homogeneous ODE with nonconstant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u= u(x,t)$ and subscript denote partial derivative with respect to the subscript.

$$u_t = u_{xx} - \frac{u_x}{x} + \frac{u}{x^2} , \;\;\;\; u(x,0) = u_0$$

I'm interested in the equilibrium solution which would solve

$$0 = u_{xx} - \frac{u_x}{x} + \frac{u}{x^2}, \;\;\;\; u(x,0) = u_0.$$

What would be the right way to solve this? I tried Fourier transform but didn't know how to deal with the $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: try guessing $u = x^\lambda$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, and solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: @900edges it is a Cauchy-Euler equation (linear, in fact). Its peculiarity is that the coefficients are not constant. And yes, the solution is unique (given an initial value), guaranteed by Picard's Theorem.